# What are the Oracle best practices to return data to c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am totally green to Oracle and I am looking for the best practice to calling and retrieving data from an Oracle DB.

In C# I can do this...

```
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = 3";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    string lastName = dr.Get<string>("A_Field_1");
```

However I want to create a stored proc in Oracle to return a data table back.
For example "Select * from MyTable".

Is it better practice to create the stored proc in Oracle, maybe utilize a function or in line in my code base?

I would prefer to create a stored proc, but I am struggling with the syntax necessary to accomplish this simple task.

Comment: It depends. I use SPs and commands. Now I prefer use some kind of ORM. Of course it depends on your architecture also.

Comment: I would prefer ORM, but limited in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is best practice to create a stored procedure rather than using dynamic SQL in your C#. In your case you can create a simple procedure like this;

```
create procedure myproc (prc out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
   open prc for SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = 3
end;
```

However, as Klaudiusz points out you, could also use some kind of ORM.